# How to format Vim quickfix entries?

Tags: vim

This is the vim-script to generate Markdown outline:

```
fun! TOC()
    call setloclist(0, [])
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    call cursor(1, 1)
    while search("^#", 'W') > 0
       let msg = printf('%s:%d:%s', expand('%'), line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), '#', '»', 'g'))
       laddexpr msg
    endwhile
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfun

com! -bar TOC call TOC()
```

---

A sample markdown file: https://github.com/progit/progit/raw/master/zh/01-introduction/01-chapter1.markdown

---

After running `:TOC` command, this is quick list:

```
01-chapter1.markdown|5| »» 关于版本控制 »»
01-chapter1.markdown|11| »»» 本地版本控制系统 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|22| »»» 集中化的版本控制系统 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|33| »»» 分布式版本控制系统 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|42| »» Git 简史 »»
01-chapter1.markdown|56| »» Git 基础 »»
01-chapter1.markdown|60| »»» 直接记录快照，而非差异比较 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|74| »»» 近乎所有操作都是本地执行 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|82| »»» 时刻保持数据完整性 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|92| »»» 多数操作仅添加数据 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|98| »»» 文件的三种状态 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|121| »» 安装 Git »»
01-chapter1.markdown|125| »»» 从源代码安装 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|152| »»» 在 Linux 上安装 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|162| »»» 在 Mac 上安装 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|177| »»» 在 Windows 上安装 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|185| »» 初次运行 Git 前的配置 »»
01-chapter1.markdown|197| »»» 用户信息 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|206| »»» 文本编辑器 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|212| »»» 差异分析工具 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|220| »»» 查看配置信息 »»»
01-chapter1.markdown|240| »» 获取帮助 »»
01-chapter1.markdown|254| »» 小结 »»
```

---

I want to format the quick fix entries to this:

```
|005| »» 关于版本控制 »»
|011| »»» 本地版本控制系统 »»»
|022| »»» 集中化的版本控制系统 »»»
|033| »»» 分布式版本控制系统 »»»
|042| »» Git 简史 »»
|056| »» Git 基础 »»
|060| »»» 直接记录快照，而非差异比较 »»»
|074| »»» 近乎所有操作都是本地执行 »»»
|082| »»» 时刻保持数据完整性 »»»
|092| »»» 多数操作仅添加数据 »»»
|098| »»» 文件的三种状态 »»»
|121| »» 安装 Git »»
|125| »»» 从源代码安装 »»»
|152| »»» 在 Linux 上安装 »»»
|162| »»» 在 Mac 上安装 »»»
|177| »»» 在 Windows 上安装 »»»
|185| »» 初次运行 Git 前的配置 »»
|197| »»» 用户信息 »»»
|206| »»» 文本编辑器 »»»
|212| »»» 差异分析工具 »»»
|220| »»» 查看配置信息 »»»
|240| »» 获取帮助 »»
|254| »» 小结 »»
```

I cannot find any option to do it. If you known, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, your (nice and useful!) implementation ignores the very first heading. (In the example, `# 起步 #` is missing.) You need to include the 'c' flag for the first `search()`: ... call cursor(1, 1) let flags = 'cW' while search("^#", flags) > 0 let flags = 'W' ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible to configure the way quickfix locations are
displayed. It is only possible to specify how to interpret them via
the `errorformat` option. However, one can use the conceal feature
to hide filenames in the quickfix or a location list window.

The following commands enable concealing and define a syntax rule
matching any text at the beginning of a line before the first
`|` character.

```
:set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nc
:syntax match qfFileName /^[^|]*/ transparent conceal
```

One can trigger these commands for every quickfix or location list
window using an auto-command. Yet, it is not a good idea in general,
since in most cases displaying filenames is a useful feature.

For the case presented in the question, it is better to make these
customizations only for the newly collected location list. It requires
opening the location list window first, though.

```
:lopen
:set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nc
:syntax match qfFileName /^[^|]*/ transparent conceal
```

Comment: The `NonText` group name suggests a link to the eponymous highlighting group. A better, more consistent name might be `qfFile`.

Comment: @Ingo:  Maybe, but using custom highlighting group name requires additional command.  Also, this custom group would be a dummy, effectively.  Because of the `transparent` and `conceal` specifiers the highlighting group is not used, and there is no highlighting to customize.

Comment: You're right, but I don't understand why you would need another command. As the highlighting group isn't used here, you don't need to define it.

Comment: @Ingo:  As a matter of fact, you are absolutely right.  I have not noticed that in this case it is not necessary to define a group first.  Thank you for a helpful comment!

Comment: Is it possible to use this method and keep highlighting? E.g. when I call vimgrep and copen, line and col numbers are highlighted yellow, but after removing file names using this method, they become colorless. Can I keep them yellow?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing this on [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) on [this PR (with GIF animation)](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/pull/71/files) using `set modifiable` + substitution instead of conceal with something along:

```
function! b:Markdown_Toc()
    silent lvimgrep '^#' %
    vertical lopen
    let &winwidth=(&columns/2)
    set modifiable
    %s/\v^([^|]*\|){2,2} #//
    for i in range(1, line('$'))
        let l:line = getline(i)
        let l:header = matchstr(l:line, '^#*')
        let l:length = len(l:header)
        let l:line = substitute(l:line, '\v^#*[ ]*', '', '')
        let l:line = substitute(l:line, '\v[ ]*#*$', '', '')
        let l:line = repeat(' ', (2 * l:length)) . l:line
        call setline(i, l:line)
    endfor
    set nomodified
    set nomodifiable
endfunction
```

But you might prefer:

```
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
```

It's up to you. =)

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fu s:TOC() abort
    call setloclist(0, [])
    let curfile = expand('%:p')
    let save_cursor = getpos('.')
    call cursor(1, 1)
    while search('^#', 'W') > 0
       let msg = printf('%s:%d:%s',
           \ curfile,
           \ line('.'), getline('.')->substitute('#', '»', 'g')
           \ )
       laddexpr msg
    endwhile
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
    call setloclist(0, [], 'r', {
        \ 'lines': getloclist(0)
        \     ->map('curfile .. "|" .. v:val.lnum .. " " .. v:val.col .. "|" .. v:val.text'),
        \ 'efm': '%f|%l %c|%m',
        \ 'quickfixtextfunc': function('s:quickfixtextfunc'),
        \ })
endfu

fu s:quickfixtextfunc(info) abort
    let ll = getloclist(a:info.winid, {'id': a:info.id, 'items': 0}).items
    let lnum_width = range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        \ ->map({_, v -> ll[v].lnum})
        \ ->max()
        \ ->len()
    let formatted_lines = []
    for idx in range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        let e = ll[idx]
        let fname = bufname(e.bufnr)->fnamemodify(':t')
        let line = printf('|%0*s| %s', lnum_width, e.lnum, e.text)
        call add(formatted_lines, line)
    endfor
    return formatted_lines
endfu

com -bar TOC call s:TOC()
```

It relies on the `'quickfixtextfunc'` attribute of a location list, which was added in these 2 Vim patches:

- [8.2.0933](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0933)  'quickfixtextfunc' does not get window ID of location list
- [8.2.0959](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0959)  using 'quickfixtextfunc' is a bit slow

See [`:h quickfix-window-function`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix-window-function).

---

For better performance, here is the same code in Vim9:

```
vim9

def TOC()
    setloclist(0, [])
    var curfile: string = expand('%:p')
    var save_cursor: list<number> = getpos('.')
    cursor(1, 1)
    while search('^#', 'W') > 0
       msg = printf('%s:%d:%s',
           curfile,
           line('.'), getline('.')->substitute('#', '»', 'g')
           )
       laddexpr msg
    endwhile
    setpos('.', save_cursor)
    setloclist(0, [], 'r', {
        lines: getloclist(0)
            ->mapnew((_, v) => curfile .. '|' .. v.lnum .. ' ' .. v.col .. '|' .. v.text),
        efm: '%f|%l %c|%m',
        quickfixtextfunc: Quickfixtextfunc,
        })
enddef
var msg: string

def Quickfixtextfunc(info: dict<number>): list<string>
    var ll: list<any> = getloclist(info.winid, {id: info.id, items: 0}).items
    var lnum_width: number = range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        ->map((_, v) => ll[v].lnum)
        ->max()
        ->len()
    var formatted_lines: list<string> = []
    for idx in range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        var e: dict<any> = ll[idx]
        var fname: string = bufname(e.bufnr)->fnamemodify(':t')
        var line: string = printf('|%0*s| %s', lnum_width, e.lnum, e.text)
        add(formatted_lines, line)
    endfor
    return formatted_lines
enddef

com -bar TOC TOC()
```

This requires a recent Vim version.  It works on 8.2.2451.