# Is there a way to change display pattern of quickfix list

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to setup a keybinding to produce a function skeleton of the current file using grep and location list. Since I'm only scanning the current file the filename at the beginning of each line is redundant and makes the output less readable. Secondly, the default display pattern removes whitespace at the begging of the message removing information about the nesting of functions.

Changing `grepformat` from the default `%f:%l:%m` to `%l:%m` removes the filename at the beginning of each line in the location list but without the name it doesn't know to look in the current file so I can't jump to the different functions.

Looking through the `errorformat` and `quickfix` documentation doesn't indicate any options for changing the quickfix\location list display pattern as far as I can tell.

This provides a keybinding for a functional location list but bad formatting:

```
grepformat=%f:%l:%m
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>l :silent lgrep! function %<CR>:lopen<CR>
```

This provides a better formatted but a non-functional location list:

```
grepformat=%l:%m
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>l :silent lgrep! -h function %<CR>:lopen<CR>
```

Notice the `-h` grep option suppress the filename in the output

The raw grep output is almost exactly how I want the code formatted:

```
1:function actigraphyCalculator(dirname)
69:     function [checkedFiles, metadata] = readQcData
75:    function fileContents = openFile(name, filePaths)
80:     function fileContents = qcprocessing(name, fileContents, metadata)
90:    function fileContents = removeBadDays(name, fileContents, metadata)
106:    function path = createSavePath(filepath)
```

The only issue is the indenting is inconsistent and the different number lengths cause the messages to not line up perfectly.

The current output for the location list of the same file is:

```
calcActigraphy/actigraphyCalculator.m|1| function actigraphyCalculator(dirname)
calcActigraphy/actigraphyCalculator.m|69| function [checkedFiles, metadata] = readQcData
calcActigraphy/actigraphyCalculator.m|75| function fileContents = openFile(name, filePaths)
calcActigraphy/actigraphyCalculator.m|80| function fileContents = qcprocessing(name, fileContents, metadata)
calcActigraphy/actigraphyCalculator.m|90| function fileContents = removeBadDays(name, fileContents, metadata)
```

Notice the lack of indentation at the beginning of the message.

Comment: You could get the quickfixlist with `getqflist(...)` and then get the lines and check the indent (or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:help :syn-conceal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-conceal) to hide the filename from the quickfix list. It's still there physically (so navigation still works), it's just not displayed any longer.

I've found the basic idea in [how to format vim quickfix entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199068/how-to-format-vim-quickfix-entry); here's a mapping that I use for it (to be put into `~/.vim/ftplugin/qf_conceal.vim`:

```
function! s:ToggleLocation()
    if ! v:count && &l:conceallevel != 0
        setlocal conceallevel=0
        silent! syntax clear qfLocation
    else
        setlocal concealcursor=nc
        silent! syntax clear qfLocation
        if v:count == 1
            " Hide file paths only.
            setlocal conceallevel=1
            " XXX: Couldn't find a way to integrate the concealment with the
            " existing "qfFileName" definition, and had to replace it. This will
            " persist when toggling off; only a new :setf qf will fix that.
            syntax match qfLocation /^\%([^/\\|]*[/\\]\)\+/ transparent conceal cchar=‥ nextgroup=qfFileName
            syntax clear qfFileName
            syntax match qfFileName /[^|]\+/ contained
        elseif v:count == 2
            " Hide entire filespec.
            setlocal conceallevel=2
            syntax match qfLocation /^[^|]*/ transparent conceal
        else
            " Hide filespec and location.
            setlocal conceallevel=2
            syntax match qfLocation /^[^|]*|[^|]*| / transparent conceal
        endif
    endif
endfunction
"[N]<LocalLeader>tf Toggle filespec and location to allow focusing on the
"           error text.
"           [N] = 1: Hide file paths only.
"           [N] = 2: Hide entire filespec.
"           [N] = 3: Hide filespec and location.
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <LocalLeader>tf :<C-u>call <SID>ToggleLocation()<CR>
```