# How to get rid of line numbers in vim quickfix list?

Tags: vim

I’m trying to use the quickfix list for output some information, like `:registers`, `:highlight`, and many other commands do. But I cannot get rid of line numbers appearing at the beginning of every line.

```
function s:sample()
    let my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'something else']
    cgetexpr my_list
    clist
endfunction
```

I expected:

```
    apple
    banana
    something else
```

I’ve got:

```
    1: apple
    2: banana
    3: something else
```

So, how to get rid of the leading numbers and colons?

Comment: The numbers are there for a reason. It enables you to jump to a specific item in the list using the `cc` command. For example `:cc 2` will jump to `banana`. If you want to disable it for aesthetic reasons, then this answer would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199068/how-to-format-vim-quickfix-entry

Comment: `setlocal nonumber norelativenumber` in `$VIMHOME/after/ftplugin/qf.vim`.

Comment: @A S The `nonumber` option doesn’t work, unfortunately. I think the numbers I want to get rid of are not the real line numbers shown for a buffer, they’re printed by the quickfix special output formatting.

Comment: @Harish That’s correct, of course. But I want to use the quickfix window just for showing information, not for jumping. Many commands, like `:registers`, `:highlight`, and others, do exactly what I want—the information they give is not intended for jumping, and doesn’t contain such numbers. How do they achieve that? I’ve carefully read the link you gave me but have not understood what exactly I have to do. I guess that the key is somewhere in the `formaterror` option. It’s the first place I started my investigation.

Comment: Check out `conceal` as explained at Vi and Vim Stack Exchange https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18353/how-to-conceal-filename-and-line-number-in-quickfix-window